# Downloading PDF across 2 APIs using GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to download a PDF file crossing over two API's with a GET Request.

If I go direct to API2 the PDF downloads fine with the below code:

```
Stream fileStream = File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
result.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
FileName = "test.pdf"
}; 
return result;
```

However when I throw API1 into the mix things get a little wonky!!

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpRequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
response.Content = new StringContent(content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF8");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
FileName = "test.pdf"
};
return response;
```

Going direct to API2 produces: %PDF-1.6%âãÏÓ

Going via API2 produces:%PDF-1.6%����

Ive tried changing ContentType and ContentEncoding on API1 with no joy.

Does anything jump out to anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.ReadAsStringAsync` on a binary document wont work - you have to call `.ReadAsByteArrayAsync`.
You also have to use `ByteArrayContent` instead of `StringContent`.

**not tested**

Comment: Thanks Michael, that worked perfect. i wont tell you how long Ive been looking at that block of code.....SQUARE EYES!!!

Comment: Thanks Michael, you saved me, as I working for days without success.