# Server/Client File Stream PDF from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, filestream

I'm trying to stream a PDF from an Azure Function that is stored in blob storage. Here's the server code:

```
[Function("GetPdf")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")],
  HttpRequestData req,
  FunctionContext executionContent)
{
  // Some code here to validate the body of the request
  // Some more code to deserialize the json from the body
  var reqBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsynce();
  var theRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheRequest>(reqBody);
  var result = new ServiceResult<MemoryStream>();
  var ms = await svc.GetPdfFromBlobStorage(theRequest.fileName);
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  // I've tested that the actual pdf is in fact a pdf
  // by saving it to the drive before sending it to the client
  return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test.pdf");
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var req = new { fileName = "the_file"};
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
  var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:7071/api/GetPdf", data);
  
  await using var ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
  await using var fs = File.Create(fileInfo.FullName);
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  ms.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

The content of the file is not a pdf but rather just plain text: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult

Any idea what I'm doing wrong that I can't receive the stream on the client side?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What's `ITaskResult`? I usually see `IActionResult`

Comment: @ESG - my bad... I fixed the code to read IActionResult.

Comment: Have you tried using  `.ReadAsByteArrayAsync`  and `ByteArrayContent` instead of `stringContent`  As per this document https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121344

Comment: Should the code line `await using var ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` be `using var ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`?

Answer (score 1):

First off I want to thank everyone for your input. Everything provided led us to the correct answer. Here's how we made it work:

Server Code

```
[Function("GetPdf")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")],
  HttpRequestData req,
  FunctionContext executionContent)
{
  // Some code here to validate the body of the request
  // Some more code to deserialize the json from the body
  var reqBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsynce();
  var theRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheRequest>(reqBody);
  var result = new ServiceResult<MemoryStream>();
  var ms = await svc.GetPdfFromBlobStorage(theRequest.fileName);
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  // I've tested that the actual pdf is in fact a pdf
  // by saving it to the drive before sending it to the client
  return new FileContentResult(ms, "application/pdf") // change octet-stream to pdf
  {
    FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
  }; 
}
```

We created a class to deserialize the json result from the server

```
public class FileResponse
{
  public byte[] FileContents {get; set;}
  public string ContentType {get; set;}
  public string FileDownloadName {get; set;}
  public DateTimeOffset? LastModified {get; set;}
  public EntityTagHeaderValue EntityTag {get; set;}
  public string {get; set;}
}
```

Then finally the client code that brings the magic all together

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var req = new { prop1 = "someVal", prop2 = "AnotherVal", prop3 = "etc..."};
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
  var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
  {
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://fakeurl/api/getpdf"),
    Content = data
  };
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("secret-key-if-your-api-is-secured", "the-secret");
  var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
  await using var ms = new MemoryStream(result.FileContents);
  await using var fs = File.Create($"c:\\temp\\{result.FileDownloadName}");
  await ms.CopytoAsync(fs);
}
```

I worked directly with [Daniel Arias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13272176/daniel-morales-arias) (@daniel-morales-arias) who found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp) and put the final code together